# How to use Cmder console with GNS3 Device's console

Tags: windows, cisco, cmder

How to use GNS3 Console for each devices with Cmder ?

Cmder is not in the list of standard GNS3 terminal.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to activate telnet on your Windows System. Enter this command on admin terminal.

```
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient
```

Second, you need to create a launch script on Cmder folder. For example `fromcli.bat`

```
@echo off
set CMDER_ROOT=%~dp0
start %CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu.exe /icon "%CMDER_ROOT%\cmder.exe" /title Cmder /loadcfgfile "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\ConEmu.xml" /cmd cmd /k "%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\init.bat cd %CD% && %~1"
```

(Reference: [Github Issue](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/457#issuecomment-132830580))

Third, go on GNS3 interface (Edit>Preferences) and (General>Console applications), click on Edit change command with

```
"<PATH TO YOUR BAT FILE>" "telnet %h %p"
```